# How to make prettier break all union types?

Tags: typescript, prettier, jsprettier

I want this:

```
type SomeType = Variant1 | Variant2
```

to always format into this:

```
type SomeType =
  | Variant1 
  | Variant2
```

No matter whether it overflows the specified column width or not.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Been scouring google to try to find one but can't

Comment: @MikeHarrison nope, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you need that degree of control over formatting you're likely not the target audience for Prettier because such things are intentionally not configurable in it. See [Prettier's option philosophy](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). That said, you still can achieve what you want by creating a fork or a plugin.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanx.