# How to declare newline after arrow function in .editorconfig?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, editorconfig

I want this:

```
const fn = () => papa
  .child1()
  .child2();
```

to look like this:

```
const fn = () => 
  papa
    .child1()
    .child2();
```

Comment: Is it the linter that is complaining?

Comment: No, I have auto formatter set up 'on save', and this is how it gets formatted. I want `papa` to go down. (Using IntelliJ btw)

Comment: editorconfig doesn't support this kid of formatting. my suggestion to you is to use prettier which has a built-in best practices. (2020 version of intellij added auto reformat with prettier on save built-in)

Comment: @felixmosh I actually started with prettier. But shortly faced it's [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61229101/592641)